# JBoss JDBC MBean Prevent Startup If Server Not Found

Tags: jdbc, jboss, mbeans, persistence-manager

During JBoss startup I have a Persistence Manager that depends on a JDBC connection (DefaultDS).  The JDBC connection starts fine whether or not it can actually connect to the database so when the Persistence Manager starts it thinks it has a connection.  Then it blows up because it cannot connect to the database and never starts.  This prevents my DestinationManager from starting and causes all kinds of headache.

Is there a way to make MBeans that depend on the JDBC connection not start unless the JDBC connection can actually connect to the database?  As an alternative, is there a way to make the JDBC connection depend on an MBean that is only active while the database can be connected to?

**tl;dr; All I need is for my MBeans/DestinationManager to wait until the database (DefaultDS) is available before booting.**

Please comment if you need more info about the enviornment.

- JBoss version 4.2.3
- Database: MsSql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, you're having a problem because even though the **DefaultDS** data source reports that it has started, since it has not acquired any connections, you don't necessarily know that *connections can be made* .

Unfortunately, even with the [prefill](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources) option enabled, the datasource service will still start normally even if it cannot make a connection.

Your best bet is to implement a [ServiceMBean](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ServiceMBeanSupport) that checks an actual connection from the datasource before it reports being started. For this example, we'll call it **org.bob.ConnChecker** and will deployed using the ObjectName **org.bob:service=ConnChecker**.

Your deployment descriptor should look something like this:

```
  <mbean code="org.bob.ConnChecker" name="jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="DataSource">jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool</depends>
  </mbean>
```

So your service will not be started until the data source has started. Your service will not start unless it can get a connection. Now you just have to add **org.bob:service=ConnChecker** as a dependency of the DestinationManager:

jboss.mq:service=MessageCache
    jboss.mq:service=PersistenceManager
    jboss.mq:service=StateManager
    jboss.mq:service=ThreadPool
    jboss:service=Naming
    org.bob:service=ConnChecker

The code for **ConnChecker** will look something like this:

```
....
import org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport;
....
public class ConnChecker extends ServiceMBeanSupport implements ConnCheckerMBean {
    /** The ObjectName of the data source */
    protected ObjectName dataSourceObjectName = null;
    /** The Datasource reference */
    protected DataSource dataSource = null;
    /**
     * Called by JBoss when the dataSource has started
     * @throws Exception This will happen if the dataSource cannot provide a connection
     * @see org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport#startService()
     */
    public void startService() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            // Get the JNDI name from the DataSource Pool MBean
            String jndiName = (String)server.getAttribute(dataSourceObjectName, "PoolJndiName");
            // Get a ref to the DataSource from JNDI
            lookupDataSource(jndiName);
            // Try getting a connection
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            // If we get here, we successfully got a connection and this service will report being Started
        } finally {
            if(conn!=null) try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
    /**
     * Configures the service's DataSource ObjectName
     * @param dataSourceObjectName The ObjectName of the connection pool
     */
    public void setDataSource(ObjectName dataSourceObjectName) {
        this.dataSourceObjectName = dataSourceObjectName;
    }
    /**
     * Acquires a reference to the data source from JNDI
     * @param jndiName The JNDI binding name of the data source
     * @throws NamingException
     */
    protected void lookupDataSource(String jndiName) throws NamingException {
        dataSource = (DataSource)new InitialContext().lookup(jndiName);
    }
}
```

The code for **ConnCheckerMBean** looks like this:

```
....
import org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport;
....
public interface ConnCheckerMBean extends ServiceMBean {
    public void setDataSource(ObjectName dataSourceObjectName);
}
```

So you will *still* get errors if connections cannot be made to the database, but the DestinationManager will not start, and hopefully that will be better than the headaches you're having now.

Comment: this is what I ended up doing, but is there anyway to have the bean wait/stall until it can get a connection.  Right now I have it spinning checking for a connection until it can get one.  But this doesn't allow the server to start.

Comment: Sure. In the startService method of ConnChecker, loop the connection test and simply sleep x seconds every time you fail to get a connection for a total y times and then throw an exception.

Comment: So there is no way to have a bunch of beans just "waiting" and still allow Jboss to boot all the way up?

Answer (score 2):

> So there is no way to have a bunch of beans just "waiting" and still
>   allow Jboss to boot all the way up?

Not in any standard fashion. The JBoss boot cycle either runs through to completion or reports a dependency failure. The process is sequential and single-threaded (until JBoss 7).

What you could do (and I only briefly tested this) is:

- Re-implement the **ConnChecker** to run its connection test in a separate thread. It will be considered started as soon as that thread is spawned.
- Pull out all the XML config files for services you want to depend on **ConnChecker** (I guess this would be all JMS deployment XML) files into another directory outside of *deploy*, say for example  ***/jboss/server/bob/late-deploy***.
- Since the late-service files are now not in the **URLDeploymentScanner**'s list of paths, they will not be deployed as part of the default deployment process.

The trick to getting the late-service files to deploy is that your new **ConnChecker** will happily spin, waiting to get a connection (and might possibly timeout and stop right there) but when it does successfully acquire a connection, it will execute code that looks like this:

```
import javax.management.*;
.....
// The JBoss URL Deployment Scanner MBean ObjectName
ObjectName on = new ObjectName("jboss.deployment:flavor=URL,type=DeploymentScanner");
// server is the JBossMBean server. ServiceMBeans automatically have this reference.
server.invoke(on, "addURL", new Object[]{new URL("file:/jboss/server/bob/late-deploy")}, new String[]{String.class.getName});
```

So what this does is tell the deployment scanner "start looking in this directory too" and a couple of seconds later, your late-services will deploy, hopefully error free. Additionally, since you added the late-service at runtime (and therefore non-persistently), when the server restarts, the deployment scanner will be reverted back to it's original configuration, waiting for **ConnChecker** to add new URLs to it.

Just make sure that the deployer has **ScanEnabled** set to true and that the **ScanPeriod** is low enough that you get the required response time to deploy your late-services once the JDBC connection is made. That MBean configuration is in

```
<jboss-home>/server/<server-name>/conf/jboss-service.xml
```

Look for this:

```
   <mbean code="org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner"
      name="jboss.deployment:type=DeploymentScanner,flavor=URL">
....
      <!-- Frequency in milliseconds to rescan the URLs for changes -->
      <attribute name="ScanPeriod">5000</attribute>
      <!-- A flag to disable the scans -->
      <attribute name="ScanEnabled">true</attribute>
....
   </mbean>
```